# Move all contents after a particular div under a different tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move all the text(html content) after a div(which is again under a div) to another tag.
For example, if i have a page like below, i want to move everything after div2 to body:

```
<body>
    <div id=div1>
      <div id=div2></div>
      <div id=div3></div>
      <script>blah</script>
      and much more
    </div>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
   <div id=div1>
      <div id=div2></div>
    </div>
    <div id=div3></div>
    <script>blah</script>
    and much more
 </body>
```

How can i do this?
Using

```
$('#div').appendTo('body');
```

only moves that div.

Comment: can there be also elements before div2 or is it always the first child element of div1?

Comment: there can be any other div's before div2 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery.

```
   var elems = $("#div2").nextAll();
    $('body').append(elems );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rJPW/)

Comment: Or just `$('#div2').nextAll().appendTo('body')`

Comment: @Blender: Thanks, its short and simple

Answer (score 0):

As of my tries, response above isn't correct because it doesn't move the text nodes.
Try this, hope it's what you are looking for:

```
​var $div = $("#div2"​), $con = $div.parent().contents();
$con.slice($con.index($div)+1).appendTo("body");
​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5V6sC/1/)